# How do I get WP Gallery image information in to loop

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, image-gallery

I'm making a slider for a site, and the images come from the WP posts' gallery, which works fine. But I want the image information in there to, such as title and description of the image. This is my current code and loop for my slider which works perfectly.

Functions.php:

```
<?php function aldenta_get_images($size = 'thumbnail') {
    global $post;

    $photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

    $results = array();

    if ($photos) {
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            // get the correct image html for the selected size
            $results[] = wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, $size);
        }
    }

    return $results;
} ?>
```

Page:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="banner">

                <ul class="rslides">
                            <?php $galleryimages = aldenta_get_images('medium');
                            foreach ($galleryimages as $galleryimage ) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php echo $galleryimage; ?>

                                <div class="slider-desc">
                                    <div class="slider-desc-text">
                                    <div class="slider-desc-title"><h1></h1></div>
                                    <div class="slider-desc-content"><?php  ?></div>
                                    <div class="slider-link"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-arrow.png"></a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </li>

                        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                </ul>
```

I just want the image information to display over the image, you can see I have no current function for this, just need to get that information in to the loop to display for each slide.

Answer (score 0):

In your function.php file you could:

```
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        // get the correct image html for the selected size
        $results[]['content'] = wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, $size);
        $results[]['title'] = get_the_title($photo->ID);
    }
```

and then

```
                        <?php $galleryimages = aldenta_get_images('medium');
                        foreach ($galleryimages as $galleryimage ) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $galleryimage['content']; ?>

                            <div class="slider-desc">
                                <div class="slider-desc-text">
                                <div class="slider-desc-title"><h1><?php echo $galleryimage['title']; ?></h1></div>
                                <div class="slider-desc-content"><?php  ?></div>
                                <div class="slider-link"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-arrow.png"></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php } ?>
```

The example here is just for getting the title. I'm sure you can do the same with the content or whatever you want (meta data for instance)

Comment: I tried this and it's close, the only problem is that it is creating new slides for the captions instead of overlaying the ['title'] on to the corresponding slide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The image `alt` text is stored in the `post_meta` table with `meta_key` `_wp_attachment_image_alt` while `title` , `caption` ,`description` are stored in `wp_posts` below is the demo how you can get these

```
$alt = get_post_meta($photo->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
if(count($alt)) echo $alt;

$image_title = $photo->post_title;
$caption = $photo->post_excerpt;
$description = $photo->post_content;
```